# How to return NIL using STDOUT in C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to solve a simple problem in Hackerrank.
Problem - Find Mth to last element.

I used the following code and it passed all the test cases in the beginning (I hardcoded NIL to pass some test cases). But after submission, I failed one of the test case. One of my question is whether it is possible to see the test case that is failing after submission (after submission, the test cases are different than before)

Here is my code: If someone can tell me what's wrong with the code, I'd die happy I guess :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        int n = 0;
        string Result = "";
        if (Int32.TryParse(number, out n))
        { }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Number input can't be read");

        string foo = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] tokens = foo.Split(' ');

        List<string> myList = tokens.ToList<string>();

        if (n < myList.Count())
        {
            myList.Reverse();
            Result = myList[n-1];

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Result);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("NIL");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: "NIL" is a string of 3 characters. If this is the intent then the code will do that, *if the appropriate line is run* (in which case the title is inappropriate). Did you mean NUL (the NULL character, in which case the title is wrong) or, is the program simply not running the expected line (in which case the title is unrelated)? Make sure to write relevant summary titles.

Comment: The challenge asks for NIL specifically:                                                                    If you are given an invalid index, output NIL instead:                                                =====
Input:

2
42
Output (2nd index for an array that contains only 1 element):

NIL

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you could change your TryParse call to `if (!Int32.TryParse(number, out n))` and eliminate the empty braces and else.